# Different touches that not react with each other objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, multi-touch

I'm making simple game for two players on Ipad, just like ping pong, when one finger is on screen player can react with his paddle, but when second finger is on his paddle, he cant move his paddle, but he move first paddle instead, I set up some `NSLog` and it says that both of them moves, but that isn't right,here are sample of my code:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
/* Called when a touch begins */
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
//First player
CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self];
SKPhysicsBody* body = [self.physicsWorld bodyAtPoint:touchLocation];

if (body && [body.node.name isEqualToString: paddleCategoryName]) {
    NSLog(@"Began touch on first paddle");
    self.isFingerOnPaddle = YES;
}
//Second player
CGPoint secondTouchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self];
SKPhysicsBody* secondbody = [self.physicsWorld bodyAtPoint:secondTouchLocation];
if (secondbody && [secondbody.node.name isEqualToString: secondPaddleCategoryName]) {
    NSLog(@"Began touch on second paddle");
    self.isSecondFingerOnPaddle = YES;
}
    }
 }

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
    //for first player
    if (self.isFingerOnPaddle) {
        CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self];
        CGPoint previousLocation = [touch previousLocationInNode:self];
        SKSpriteNode* paddle = (SKSpriteNode*)[self childNodeWithName: paddleCategoryName];
        int paddleY = paddle.position.y + (touchLocation.y - previousLocation.y);
        paddleY = MAX(paddleY, paddle.size.height/2);
        paddleY = MIN(paddleY, self.size.height - paddle.size.height/2);
        paddle.position = CGPointMake(paddle.position.x, paddleY);
        NSLog(@"First paddle moving");

    }
    //for second player
    if (self.isSecondFingerOnPaddle) {
        CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self];
        CGPoint previousLocation = [touch previousLocationInNode:self];
        SKSpriteNode* secondPaddle = (SKSpriteNode*)[self childNodeWithName: secondPaddleCategoryName];
        int secondPaddleY = secondPaddle.position.y + (touchLocation.y - previousLocation.y);
        secondPaddleY = MAX(secondPaddleY, secondPaddle.size.height/2);
        secondPaddleY = MIN(secondPaddleY, self.size.height - secondPaddle.size.height/2);
        secondPaddle.position = CGPointMake(secondPaddle.position.x, secondPaddleY);
        NSLog(@"Second paddle moving");
    }
}
}
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
self.isFingerOnPaddle = NO;
self.isSecondFingerOnPaddle = NO;
 }
```

What I do wrong, and what do I need to change to my code work, like it should

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better approach would be to sub class paddle and do your touch code inside the paddle subclass.  This eliminates having to loop through touch arrays to see if your paddle is being touched, plus it makes the code a lot neater and easier to read.  The only thing is you will have to style your node set up a little differently, because touch moved will not work outside of the paddle.

Here is how you style it

> 1) Subclass Paddle to SKNode
>   2) Create a child of SKSpriteNode for your actual paddle gfx
>   3) Paddle frame should be set at the width of your scene, with a height that is allowed for the player to touch (probably the height of the paddle gfx)
>   4) override the touch code inside Paddle,  all touch code in the set should only relate to what is being touched by the paddle
>   5) Do all of your sliding logic inside these overrides

Now you have Paddle defined for the behavior you are looking for, you can add it to the scene where ever you like.

The nice part about this method is you eliminate a lot of duplicate code, (Since the paddles on both sides behave differently) and if you want to add some fun, you can add even more paddles to both sides to provide more variation.  (Each player has a paddle in the middle of the play field, and the bottom, which can be moved independantly)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion,I definitely will use your suggestion about add more paddles, it sounds awesome.

Comment: Well the main point was to write code that is reusable, and avoid duplication

Answer (score 1):

your logic is wrong, just add a touchArray property to store first touch and second touch, set it when touch begin then determine when touches moved.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
    /* Called when a touch begins */
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {

        CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self];
        SKSpriteNode *node = (SKSpriteNode *)[self nodeAtPoint:touchLocation];

        if (node && [node.name isEqualToString: paddleCategoryName]) {
            NSLog(@"Began touch on first paddle");

            [self.touchArray replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:touch];

        }else if (node && [node.name isEqualToString: secondPaddleCategoryName]) {
            NSLog(@"Began touch on second paddle");

            [self.touchArray replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:touch];

        }

    }
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self];

        UITouch *firstTouch = self.touchArray[0];
        UITouch *secondTouch = self.touchArray[1];

        SKSpriteNode *paddle = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] init];

        if (touch == firstTouch) {
            CGPoint previousLocation = [touch previousLocationInNode:self];
            SKSpriteNode* paddle = (SKSpriteNode*)[self childNodeWithName: paddleCategoryName];
            int paddleY = paddle.position.y + (touchLocation.y - previousLocation.y);
            paddleY = MAX(paddleY, paddle.size.height/2);
            paddleY = MIN(paddleY, self.size.height - paddle.size.height/2);
            paddle.position = CGPointMake(paddle.position.x, paddleY);
            NSLog(@"First paddle moving");

        }else if (touch == secondTouch) {
            CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self];
            CGPoint previousLocation = [touch previousLocationInNode:self];
            SKSpriteNode* secondPaddle = (SKSpriteNode*)[self childNodeWithName: secondPaddleCategoryName];
            int secondPaddleY = secondPaddle.position.y + (touchLocation.y - previousLocation.y);
            secondPaddleY = MAX(secondPaddleY, secondPaddle.size.height/2);
            secondPaddleY = MIN(secondPaddleY, self.size.height - secondPaddle.size.height/2);
            secondPaddle.position = CGPointMake(secondPaddle.position.x, secondPaddleY);
            NSLog(@"Second paddle moving");
        }


    }
}
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        if (touch == self.touchArray[0]) {
            [self.touchArray replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:@""];
        }else if (touch == self.touchArray[1]) {
            [self.touchArray replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:@""];

        }
    }

    self.isFingerOnPaddle = NO;
    self.isSecondFingerOnPaddle = NO;
}
```

Comment: sorry, i don't understand how to set up array, can you show me?

Comment: self.touchArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"", @"", nil];

Comment: Putting a string into an array of touches (and casting, i.e. lying) later into touches is a keen idea.

Comment: @Eiko you have better offer?

Comment: A very simple approach would be to store those two touches in separate properties and nil them out. But treating treating an NSString as an UITouch is almost guaranteed to crash later on when you don't think about it.